# What +1 Ob penalty can you shrug off with an Ob 5 Survival test?

Tags: skills, burning-wheel

In the description of the Survival skill in Burning Wheel Gold p.303 it reads:

> **Obstacles:** [...]
>   Shrug off +1 Ob penalty, Ob 5.

The Chapter **The Anatomy of Injury** p. 497 heading **Clearing the Cobwebs** describes how to shrug off a +1 Ob penalty from a Superficial Wound via a Ob 2 Health test which takes 2 actions during Fight and lasts until the end of the scene. Does it refer to this +1 Ob penalty?

If the option in the Survival refers to the +1 Ob from Superficial Wounds, how does it differ from the shrugging off with the Ob 2 Health test? Does it last longer than one scene but takes a longer time (according to p. 33 Survival skill checks take anywhere from minutes to days)?

If it doesn't refer to Superficial Wounds, what +1 Ob penalty does this shrug off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference to BW forums (thread started by the same person as here), without an excellent answer: https://www.burningwheel.com/forum/showthread.php?16311-What-do-you-shrug-off-with-a-Ob-5-Survival-test

I don't see any particular reason to assume the survival skill directly removes wound penalties. (It would be a reasonable FoRK or linked test for healing skills in some situations.)

The rules for weather are scarce in BW. The Gold index only lists the entry in the chapter on range and cover. My interpretation, based on what the rest of the skill does, is that the skill negates an obstacle penalty caused by weather and also reminds the GM to use obstacle penalties as the consequences of weather.

Quote from the BW forums, by Shaun Hayworth:

> Giving out persistent Ob penalties is a pretty standard failure consequence, especially in situations where the characters are facing physical hardships - cold, weather, starvation. ... I imagine the Survival Ob is about managing to scrounge stuff from the wild to mitigate those sort of things.